# c++ sqlite3_exec unable to close due to unfinalised statements

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have the following piece of code using Sqlite3 on Ubuntu (c++):

```
void test_function(dbHandler)
{
    char *retError = 0;

    std::string sql("INSERT INTO LOG (LAST_CHANGED_DATE_TIME) VALUES ('TEST');");

    int returnStatus = sqlite3_exec(dbHandler, sql.c_str(), 0, 0, &retError);

    std::cout << "RetStatus = " << returnStatus << "; " << retError << s

    if (returnStatus == SQLITE_OK)
        return sqlite3_changes(dbHandler);
    else
    {
        sqlite3_free(retError);
        sqlite3_close(dbHandler);
    }
}
```

The `sqlite3_exec` statement `sql` is made wrong to test its failture behaviour (in that case the field name does not match). I get a correct status from `sqlite3_exec` as:

```
 Status = 1; table Log has no column named last_changed_date_time
```

As it is an error, I need to free the error message (`retError`) and close the database connection. And here is where I have a problem:

When calling `sqlite3_close`, I´m getting the following exception message:

```
unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups
```

I´ve browsed around sqlite3 docs and could not find out what I´m not releasing  here...

Based on that I need help to:

a) Fix the above code.

b) Understand the correct way to recover from sqlite3_exec in case of error.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Show all other DB calls that are executed between opening the database and this function.

Comment: The only this I do is issuing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LOG` using the same `sql_exec` structure... I´m figuring out that this might be the problem...

Comment: Unfinalized statements are finalized with [`sqlite3_finalize(sqlite3_stmt*)`](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_finalize) and unfinised backups are finished with [`sqlite3_backup_finish()`](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3backupfinish). One can expect you end up in this state from a previous `sqlite3_` call. Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @qarma: I doubt any answer will really help your situation unless you tell us what db calls are being executed before you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The output line that should end with `std::endl;`. The `dbHandler` argument must have a type. A void function cannot not return a value. However, with respect to using the sqlite3 api, the posted code is correct.

b) In case of an error `sqlite3_exec` will do the recovery. You only need to free the memory pointed to by `retError`, using `sqlite3_free`, which you're already doing.

Below is a minimal running example with the 3 errors I described fixed. It shows that it is correct (the "library routine called out of sequence" output is because you cannot call `sqlite3_errmsg` on a closed database handle), as it does not produce the error you describe. So if `sqlite3_close` fails, that is because of an error elsewhere in your program.

The error you describe can be reproduced by uncommenting the 3 commented lines. The statement that will then be created by `sqlite3_prepare` is not cleaned up by a call to `sqlite3_finalize` and therefore `sqlite3_close` will cause the "unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups" error. Your error is likely caused by something similar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>

void test_function(sqlite3 * dbHandler)
{
    char *retError = 0;

    std::string sql("INSERT INTO LOG (LAST_CHANGED_DATE_TIME) VALUES ('TEST');");

    int returnStatus = sqlite3_exec(dbHandler, sql.c_str(), 0, 0, &retError);

    std::cout << "RetStatus = " << returnStatus << "; " << retError << std::endl;

    if (returnStatus == SQLITE_OK)
        return; // sqlite3_changes(dbHandler);
    else
    {
        sqlite3_free(retError);
        sqlite3_close(dbHandler);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    sqlite3 * dbHandler;
    sqlite3_open("test.sqlite", &dbHandler);
    sqlite3_exec(dbHandler, "CREATE TABLE LOG (DUMMY);", 0, 0, 0);

    // sqlite3_stmt * test;
    // const char * sql = "INSERT INTO LOG (DUMMY) VALUES ('TEST');";
    // sqlite3_prepare(dbHandler, sql, -1, &test, 0);

    test_function(dbHandler);

    std::cout << "Last error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(dbHandler) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll take that (I'm not OP), still I'd like to mention that it is possible to hit `unable to close` without explicit call to `sqlite3_prepare()` anywhere in the program; my usage was completely different, and yet this question was the closest that googled for this error code. Thus the bounty. Perhaps it comes down to sqlite "preparing" something for you when you don't expect it?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm revisiting sqlite3 since upgrading after 10 years I managed to get the above message. I did a `sqlite3_open_v2` and then a `sqlite3_close` and got the same message. `sqlite3_close_v2` avoids the message.

Small, idiot mistake, but perhaps useful to someone.